# Configuration file did not export a config object, failed loading configuration file. Protractor error

Tags: jasmine, protractor

On running the command 'Protractor conf.js' i get an error failed to load configuration file. I am unable to rectify it. Below is the configuration file and the test case file code.

conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  specs: ['todo-spec.js'],


  onPrepare: function() {
 browser.get('http://tmpcmamva07:8888/');
 browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();﻿
 jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 90000;
    element(by.model('username')).sendKeys('nagabhup');
    element(by.model('password')).sendKeys('welcomE@123');
    element(by.buttonText('Login')).click();
    browser.sleep(2000);
    browser.waitForAngular();
}
};
```

todo-spec.js

```
describe('LockTest', function() {
  it('LockTheScenarioTest', function() {
  var reportsTest = element(by.repeater('row in BaseCollection').row(0));
   reportsTest.element(by.id('22090')).click();
   reportsTest.element(by.id('22090')).element(by.xpath('following-sibling::ul')).click();
   browser.sleep(4000);
    browser.waitForAngular();
    element(by.buttonText('Ok')).click();
   expect(element(by.binding('signInName')).getText()).
        toEqual('Pratham Nagabhushan');
   });
});
```

I am not sure because of what it is unable to work. Please suggest ideas of the possible issue.

Comment: Include the entire file path of the conf file like this "Protractor C:\protractor_tests\conf.js"

Answer (score 1):

When I copy-paste your config into WebStorm, it is complaining about an extra character after the `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();﻿` line:

[image]

Remove it and you should be good to go.